# Xamarin.iOS Archive error Codesign exited with code 1 (Visual Studio 2022)

Tags: ios, visual-studio, xamarin

Its been a very stressful 3 days attempting to archive this iOS project. I hope someone can help. I have searched the entire internet twice and tied everything ive come across to no avail.

Okay to start, it Builds fine and deploys within the simulator on my Macbook). Im using a windows machine with remote deployment to my Macbook

1. Certificate has been created for Development and Distribution
2. Provisioning profile is in place
3. Configuration -> Release,  Platform -> iPhone
4. Trust Authority - Apple Worlwide Developer (Latest with expiry 2030)
5. Bundle id in plist matches com.companyname.{appname}

[image]

Only issue i cannot seem to solve is Automatic Provisioning, if i change this i get the following error. Im assuming i need to setup a specific device for this. Ive setup my macbook in devices, but it would appear that because im using windows , the device id needs to be the windows machine to be recognised and is not using the remote machine (UUID for windows is not recognised and there is no option of Windows within the developer portal).

[image]

Looks to be failing on creating the provisioning profile. Not sure how this works with automatic but assuming its trying to use that visual studio wild card.

Error when i archive (note the issue is not related to vlc, removing causes an error on a different control) seen alot of posts about this error message being invalid in reference to the control.

[image]

Thanks to all who takes a look
Kevin

Comment: Does the problem(archive error) persist if you choose `Manual provisioning ` ?

Comment: Yes, Manual previsioning is the way Microsoft say to do this. Ive even hooked an ipad up with automatic provisioning and can deploy there (app crashing when downloading images, not happening on the simulator though)

Comment: Can you try to delete all the provisioning profile and reinstall them , and then try first in Xcode to see if it works ?  If it works in Xcode , it should be able to work in Visual Studio.

Comment: Ive tried this many times, deleted certificates, created new ones on mac, deleted old ones in keychain, delete profiles and certificates from AppData\Local\Xamarin\iOS. Followed videos

Closest ive gotten (once) was was an archive but when i clicked on distribute, it asks for a certificate and profile, nothing available in drop down. This shit is crazy, dont know how anyone works like this. very frustrating

Comment: It could be a potential issue with `VS for windows`, you can use `VS for Mac` to archive , I just tried it and it's working .

Comment: When i attempt this it says it cannot find system.drawing.common , any ideas?

Comment: It seems like some third-party requires the library `system.drawing.common` , try to update them to the latest to see if problem persists.